# How does a wi-fi Linux driver work with its chipset over USB?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, wireless-access-point, wifi-driver

I am thinking of buying an usb-connected adapter . Provided a driver for its chipset is available, is it enough for it to work?

How can a wi-fi chipset driver work with a USB-connected adapter? Is there some protocol over USB which enables chipset drivers to work with USB-connected hardware?

I am going to use it on Linux.

Comment: USB is a bus, just like PCI and PCIe, but has the added complexity of hot plugging.  So a peripheral device such as a wifi module over USB is not that different from the PCIe version.  Besides the device driver, you would need the various userspace support utilities for 802.11 networking.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a Linux driver for the chip that you want to use, then it should work the same way it works on Windows. The driver should communicate via USB itself.